# VBA: matching cells from different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master sheet being updated by other workbooks. "Column A" in the Master has an ID number, the other spreadsheets will also have a column let's say "B" containing that ID number.

I want to match the ID number from the other workbook to the master and where it matches in column A pull over other columns into the master to fill in the blanks under the correct headings.

I was given this macro, but it's not matching any data.

```vb
Sub Macro1()

Dim mastersheet As Worksheet
Set mastersheet = ActiveSheet
For a = 2 To 1000
    ValueToCheck = Cells(a, 1).Value
    fname = "File location"
    Dim Workbooktocheck As Workbook
    Set Workbooktocheck = Workbooks.Open("filename")
    For b = 2 To 1000
        valueInNew = Workbooktocheck.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(b, 12)
        If ValueToCheck = valueInNew Then
            mastersheet.Cells(a, 3).Value = Workbooktocheck.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(b, 7)
        End If
    Next b
Next a

End Sub
```

***Update***
This is the master:

[image]

This is the spreadsheet that updates:

[image]

Comment: I've indented your code to make it easier to parse visually. That said, you should `Dim` and `Set` `Workbooktocheck ` outside your loop, after you've `Dim`ed and `Set` `mastersheet`. "it doesn't seem to work" is kind of vague. What exactly happens when you run the macro?

Comment: It runs end to end and the second spreadsheet opens but it does nothing. I know the matching criteria is in both spreadsheet but I’m not sure they are matching within values and nothing else is being pulled through either.

Comment: A bit more simple - master spreadsheet ID in col A - other spreadsheet ID in Col L. I need to compare these columns and if there is a match pull col A,B and C from spreadsheet into master to fill in the blanks under the correct headings

Comment: When you open a workbook, doesn't vba make it the active one? I'm guessing but would suggest to set the master workbook as a variable and add it to the range in the if check (for example masterwb.mastersheet.Cells(a, 3).Value =...)

Answer (score 2):

`Match()` is usually faster than a nested loop as long as you're only expecting a single matched row.

Try this:

```vb
Sub Macro1()

    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, wbToCheck As Workbook, wsCheck As Worksheet
    Dim ValueToCheck, a As Long, m
    
    Set wsMaster = ActiveSheet
    Set wbToCheck = Workbooks.Open("filepathgoeshere")
    Set wsCheck = wbToCheck.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<<< was missing this
    
    For a = 2 To wsMaster.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
        ValueToCheck = wsMaster.Cells(a, 1).Value
        If Len(ValueToCheck) > 0 Then
            'match is faster than using a nested loop
            m = Application.Match(ValueToCheck, wsCheck.Range("L:L"), 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                'got a match
                With wsMaster.Rows(a)
                    .Columns("C").Value = wsCheck.Cells(m, "G").Value
                    'etc for other cells...
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm getting a "Object variable not set (Error 91)" for 'm = Application.Match(ValueToCheck, wsCheck.Range("L:L"), 0)'

Answer (score 1):

### Update Master Worksheet

- Carefully adjust the values in the constants section.
- s - `Source` (read from), d - `Destination` (written to)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateMaster()

    Const sPath As String = "C:\Test\Source.xlsx"
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sCol As String = "L"
    Const sColsList As String = "A,B,C"
    Const sfRow As Long = 1 ' header row
    
    Const dName As String = "Master"
    Const dCol As String = "A"
    Const dfRow As Long = 1 ' header row
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sPath)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dName)
    
    ' Headers
    
    Dim sCols() As String: sCols = Split(sColsList, ",")
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(sCols)
    
    Dim dCols() As Long: ReDim dCols(0 To cUpper)
    
    Dim cIndex As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To cUpper
        cIndex = Application.Match( _
            sws.Rows(sfRow).Columns(sCols(n)), dws.Rows(dfRow), 0)
        If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
            dCols(n) = cIndex
        Else
            MsgBox "A header was not found", vbCritical, "Update Master"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next n
    
    ' Column Ranges
    
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Cells(sfRow + 1, sCol)
    Dim slCell As Range: Set slCell = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, sCol).End(xlUp)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(sfCell, slCell)
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dfRow + 1, dCol)
    Dim dlCell As Range: Set dlCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dCol).End(xlUp)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(dfCell, dlCell)
    
    ' Write
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim rIndex As Variant
    For Each dCell In drg.Cells
        rIndex = Application.Match(dCell.Value, srg, 0)
        If IsNumeric(rIndex) Then
            For n = 0 To cUpper
                dCell.EntireRow.Columns(dCols(n)).Value _
                    = srg.Cells(rIndex).EntireRow.Columns(sCols(n)).Value
            Next n
        End If
    Next dCell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform
    
    MsgBox "Data updated.", vbInformation, "Update Master"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for this. I'm still a little confused on how it works, i have updated my questions with an imagine of what i need. Will this work for that?

Comment: Yes, that's it. You just have to adjust the 8 constants. You didn't mention what the name of the destination (master) worksheet is. Your images do not contain the row and column headings and the resulting image is missing. The code will find the resulting columns according to the source column titles (headers). You said it has to find a match in column `L` and copy the values in the same row of columns `A, B, C`. If that's changed, change it in the code. I don't know the path of your source workbook. Don't know what's the problem? Feel free to share any of it.